# Why can we treat systems of linear differential equations as systems of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

The system of linear equations in vector/matrix form is given by $$\textbf{b=Ax}$$
Learning linear algebra I've always thought that both vectors and matrix in this equation are filled with numbers and all the theory about linear systems is based on this fact (am I wrong?).

It is clear for me that we indeed can write system of first order differential equations in vector/matrix form as $$\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{x=Ax}$$ I understand that if we unroll this into separate equations we would in fact get our original ODE's. But it just seems to me as a hacky notational trick mostly. I wouldn't think myself that we can now apply linear algebra simply because we can write it like that.

I mean this time **x** is vector of functions, and $\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{x}$ is vector of derivatives. It's not obvious for me at all that we can still treat this construction as linear algebra original equation and apply all the rules exactly the same way, even though there are now functions and operators in place of numbers. Doesn't it kind of changes everything / or may change is some cases? Why not?

P.S. I don't know if my confusion comes from differential equations or maybe I lack understanding of linear algebra in its full generality. Could something like that be correct and useful linear algebra construction as well? $$\int_{}^{}\textbf{b=Ax}$$
$$\sin(\textbf{b})=\textbf{Ax}$$
Integration is linear, sine is not, so sine would probably never go like that?

Comment: The system of ODEs should be Ax=x', without that b there...

Comment: And no, you cannot treat systems of ODEs excatly as systems of linear equations, simply because they are not systems of linear equations. It is therefore good that it is not clear to you why we can: we can't.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thank you for your clarification. Would it be more helpful to think about systems of linear ODEs and systems of linear equations as independent concepts, that just happen to share a lot in common (including similar vector/matrix notation)?

Comment: They share the property of being linear problems — when you have two solutions, their sum is also a solution. It is certainly more helpful not to think of the two things are the same thing, since they are not the same thing!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez and I guess any linear problem can be reduced to solving system linear algebraic equations? Which is exactly what happens with system of linear ODE's?

Comment: Solutions to homogeneous *linear* differential equations are exactly elements of the kernel of a certain linear operator on a certain function space. I don't know myself, but apparently methods of linear algebra and more importantly functional analysis can be very usefully applied to the study of differential equations

Comment: @FShrike thank you for reformulating this in terms of operators and function spaces, it will be useful to investigate those.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that that's what happens to ODEs: as I wrote twice, ODEs and linear equations are different things and  solving ODEs does.not "reduce" in any sense to solving linear equations.

Comment: You are mixing the fact that  a linear ODE is linear with the idea that it can be solved using linear algebra.

Comment: Knowing that an equation is linear helps you in solving it as much as knowing that a piano is made out of wood in playing Chopin.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez it's even harder then I thought :) I may need to revisit this some other time after some more practice probably

Answer (score 1):

> "I've always thought that both vectors and matrix in this equation are filled with numbers and all the theory about linear systems is based on this fact (am I wrong?)."

Yes, you are wrong. The theory of linear algebra is based on the fact that matrices act on column vectors linearly, that is, $A(x+cy)=Ax+cAy$ for any two vectors $x,y$ and any number $c$. If *any* mathematical object behaves the same way, the theory of linear algebra applies. The differential operator $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$ behaves the same way in relation to functions:

$$\frac{\mathrm d(f+cg)}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}+c\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dx}$$

so the theory of linear algebra applies.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that system of linear ODE's is a special case of the most general system of linear equations Ax=b, where x is vector of functions and b is vector of their derivatives? Moreover we can represent any linear operator in this form (integration for example)?

Comment: No, it would.not be correct

Answer (score 0):

Write it as a differential form in $dt$

$$ d \mathbb x(t)  \ = \ \mathbb A(t) \mathbb x(t) dt$$

This is the limit of the dicrete equation

$$ \mathbb x(t_i+ dt) \ = \ \mathbb x(t_i)  + \mathbb A(t_i)\ \mathbb \x(t_i) dt$$

So each time step is indeed a small change by the image of a linear map on the current value of the vector.

Crucial is here that $\mathbb A(t)$ is time dependent. That implies, that the matrices at different times do not commute and sorting products produces extra terms.

If $\mathbb A(t)$ is a constant matrix, the solution  is the exponential of the factor times $t$

$$  \mathbb x(t) == e^{(t-t0) \mathbb A}  \mathbb x(t0)$$

Proof by differentiation of the power series. No problem with the exponential series, that converges in any norm on finite matrices. Convincing first argument: diagonalize $\mathbb A$. The exponential function maps onto the diagonal.

In the case of a time dependent matrix $\mathbb A(t)$, the solution is similar up to the delicate effect, that the powers at different times in the time discrete approximation are not time ordered with latest factor to the left, so it comes down as the first  factor in

$$  e^{::\int_0^{t+dt}\ \mathbb A(s) ds }\ = e^{::\int_t^{t+tdt} \ \mathbb A(s) ds::}  \ e^{\int_0^t \mathbb A(s) ds ::}  =
   ( \mathbb A(t) dt) \ e^{\int_0^t \mathbb A(s) ds ::}$$

This sign $::    ::$ for time ordering of integrals over noncommuting entities is the central problem in quantum  field theory (QFT).

Comment: It is difficult to imagine an explanation less useful to the OP or anyone in his position than one involving time ordered products

Comment: Just the opposite. Enlightenment is the process to learn, that all the angels shifting planets around on the firmament are of the same quality as all the virtual particles, populating  those integrals in physics, the emtpty space and, of course,  the magazines, today.